# Laravel 10 how to define a Microsoft SQL Server schema on Migrations?

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, database-schema, laravel-10

I'm trying to work with Laravel 10 and have noticed that when trying to define a Microsoft SQL Server schema on my migrations or in the database config file the artisan command either segmentation faults, or the schema prefix is ignored and my tables are created in the dbo schema.

I've tried defining my table names like you would in a SQL Server statement as `schema_name.table_name` to try and create my tables in the desired `schema_name` like so

```php
public function up(){
    Schema::create('schema_name.table_name', function(Blueprint $table){
        //...
    });
}
```

I've also tried going into the `database.php` config file to my sqlsrv connection and setting the prefix option like so:

```json
    'connection' => [
        //...
        'sqlsrv' => [
            //...
            'prefix' => 'schema_name.',
        ],
    ],
```

Both of these just cause the `php artisan migrate` command to segmentation fault. If I remove the period that's separating the schema_name from the table_name the command will run, but will create the tables in the `dbo` schema and just smoosh the two strings together to create a `schema_nametable_name` table.

I've also tried adding a `prefix` options on my sqlsrv connection in the database.php config file as I noticed the Postgres SQL connection has it as being definable like so:

```json
    'connection' => [
        //...
        'sqlsrv' => [
            //...
            'schema' => 'schema_name',
        ],
    ],
```

But it doesn't do anything.

I'm starting to think I'd have to dig through the actual core files of the Framework to find where the actual SQL statements are being generated for these migrations and either modify them directly or create a Facade/ServiceContainer or something to extend the functionality or something.

Comment: Unless something's changed in the meantime Laravel only supports schema names for table creation on Postgres, ref: [Cannot set different schema on database config #35070](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/35070)

Comment: I haven't tried this, but a possible workaround could be to use a different SQL Login for the migrations whose default schema in the target database is the one you wish to create the tables in.

Comment: Yeah that's sort of the workaround I've got going currently. I've changed the default schema on my development SQL account and the migrations will migrate where I want them to.

Does seem odd though that Laravel doesn't support schema names outside of Postgres

Comment: It just seems odd because it looks like the actual SQL Statement Laravel is using when creating tables with a SQL Server connection is literally just `create table` with the table name and columns being appended to the string via a variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Digging deeper I can't find anything in the code that will allow for the defining of a SQL Server schema on the migration. But as [AlwaysLearning](https://stackoverflow.com/users/390122/alwayslearning) suggested setting up a specific SQL Server account that has its default schema set to the desired SQL Server schema will allow your migrations to create tables in the desired schema.